# 3d acceleration for acer travelmate 5740z

Tags: graphics, acer, 3d, hardware-acceleration

Hi I have installed ubuntu 12 and I wonder if there is 3d acceleration support for my graphic card: 
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
  I tested with glxgears and the result it's as it follows:
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.988 FPS
  Shouldn't suppose to be higher with 3d acceleration support?

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behaviour. See also the message printed by `glxgears`:

```
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
```

`glxgears` is not a benchmark, but a tool for checking whether 3D acceleration works properly. It looks like it's working as there are no other errors. To test your graphics capabilities, go watch a full-screen HD video.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Lekensteyn. I didn't know that before.